# Edit item in GridView doesn't work

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8

I'm create a GridView which displays all the employees, I can select one of the employees and click edit button to direct to edit page, all of the properties of the selected employee are bound to `TextBox` or `ComboBox`. After changing the properties, click Save button back to the `GridView` Page. But, the employee information in GridView doesn't changed. My Employee Class has implemented `INotifyPorpertyChanged` interface, the GridView's ItemsSource is `ObservableCollection`.

The binding mode of the controls in edit page is TwoWay binding.

In my constructor of MainPage, the code as below:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MyGridView.ItemsSource = Employees;  
    }
```

This is the Edit button click event handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        emp= MyGridView.SelectedItem as Employee;
        if (emp!= null)
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(EditPage), emp);
        }
    }
```

This is the Save button click event handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: show me your Page_Load event of both pages...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked whether the changed information arrived in the coresponding properties?

If so: gets the event fired? Is an event handler attached?

Christoph

Comment: After debug, I found the property in the object is changed, but when back to MainPage, the constructor of MainPage run again, it create a new instance of ObservableCollection<Employee>, so the property changed back, how to solve it?

Comment: You should not instantiate your data bound collections in your control. That should be in your ViewModel (Model). Seperating your data from your ui should solve your problem.

Comment: If I mistake something. You could post some more code for clarification. Such as the code behind of your control.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a problem of **Page.IsPostback**, Use **Page.IsPostback** Property of Page on Page_Load event just like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
       // Put your code here..
      }
    }
```

Your value get changed but when your page gets load again it gets old value because i think there is no **Page.IsPostback** in your Page_Load.Use ISPostback Property of page and your problem will get solved.For more knowledge check [MSDN Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to notice :
- Make sure when you save on Edit Page the information is stored in exact store (db etc..)
- when you navigate back to MainPage you are populating you view-model with loading latest information you save.

However in window 8 you why go for INotifyPorpertyChanged when you have built in BindableBase.cs class available in common folder.